# Jenkins refresh environmental variables for Python Plugin to work

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to have Jenkins job install python for me and then execute the script with **Python Plugin**.

So far I get the python and install it just fine, I also set the environmental variable for python, but ***plugin won't start***:

> The system cannot find the file specified FATAL: command execution
>   failed java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory
>   "C:\Jenkins\workspace\install and configure python"): CreateProcess
>   error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

As far as I understand, that this is happening **because python.exe is not in the PATH**. So I've tried:
1) add it to PATH within batch -FAILED
2) Add to PATH variable within job to "Prepare an environment for the run" with Environment Injector Plugin -FAILED

So my guess is that I have to reset the *java.library.path* of the Node or restart the Jenkins slave agent.

QUESTION: Any ideas how it could be done?

Here is what I have so far as a "Windows batch command" for python installation:

```
::verify installation is needed
python --version
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 EXIT 0

:: get the wget utility
cscript.exe .\web\vbs\download-wget.vbs

::get python 27 from server
wget.exe --no-check-certificate https://qaa.myserver.com/public/python27/python-2.7.3.msi

::install python
msiexec /i python-2.7.3.msi /qn TARGETDIR=c:\Python27

::because of the stupid bug https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3425
set temppath=%PATH:"=%
setx PATH "%temppath%" /m
```

After this is I have 2-nd build step via Python plugin `print "Hello, World"`

Comment: why you do that? Portability? You have just hardcoded the python location in the script... which is against enviroment portability. I suggest to make the build fail if python is missing. If you want a fresh python install on each build try virtualenv http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Comment: @Sammyrulez I want for ease of configuration. Should I need another slave I can run this job on it and then the run the real tests (that require python and a lot of its libraries to be present). Secondly, hardcoding the installation path doesn't bother me at all, since I'm adding the same path to PATH variable and any further calls would be just `python some.py` - doesn't matter where the python is.   Does it make sense?

Comment: @papaiatis, unfortunately no. After I run the job of installing and configuring Python I have to restart the Jenkins slave.